The definition on vacuum-vacuum amplitude with current in chapter of External Field Method of Weinberg's QFT
I'm reading Vol. 2 of Weinberg's QFT. As what I learnt from both P&S and Weinberg, the generating function is defined as
$$
Z[J] = \int \mathcal{D}\phi \exp(iS_{\text{F}}[\phi] + i\int d^4x\phi(x) J(x)).\tag{16.1.1+9.34}
$$
The P&S calculate out it
$$
Z[J] = Z_0 \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\int d^4xd^4y J(x)D_F(x-y)J(y))\tag{9.39}
$$
where $D_F(x-y)$ is free propagator and $Z_0 = Z[0]$. It seems that the sum of vacuum-vacuum graphs with current should be $Z_0^{-1}Z[J]$
But Weinberg just define straightly the vacuum-vacuum graphs with current as $Z[J]$ without factor $Z_0^{-1}$. My question is: Is this just a new convention of notation or does there exist some discrepancies of concepts?
Edit: The definition of vacuum-vacuum amplitude with current in Weinberg is eqs (16.1.1) at p63 in Vol. 2

I don't have Weinberg to hand, but it is possible that he has absorbed the $Z_0^{-1}$ into his definition of ${\mathcal D}\phi$.

@mikestone thank you for your inspiration. I'm not sure, but may be not. Since Weinberg write $\mathcal{D}\phi$ explicitly in $\prod_{y} d\phi(y)$ there.

I'd certainly include the $Z_0^{-1}$ in my amplitude.


$Z_0=Z[J\!=\!0]$ in eq. (9.39) is the functional determinant from the Gaussian integration of the path integral with a quadratic action. See also how P&S complete the square in eqs. (9.37)-(9.38).

$e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}W_0}=Z_0=Z[J\!=\!0]$ could in principle depend on physical parameters, such as e.g. a mass parameter $m$. Here $W_0$ is represented by a Feynman diagram $\bigcirc$.

Be aware that the path integral measure
$${\cal D}\phi~=~\prod_i d\phi(x_i)\tag{9.20}$$
often contains an implicitly written overall normalization constant ${\cal N}$. This is partly due to the fact that the infinite product measure (9.20) is an underspecified/incomplete mathematical definition to begin with.

The normalization constant ${\cal N}$ is cancelled between the numerator and the denominator in any $n$-point correlation functions, cf. e.g. eqs. (9.18) and (16.1.4).


References:

S. Weinberg, Quantum Theory of Fields, Vol. 2, 1996; section 16.1.

M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, An Intro to QFT, 1995; section 9.2.



Thanks for answering my question. Could you give me an example on the case that normalization constant is absorbed in definition of measure, such as some textbooks or snippets using this definition?

I updated the answer.

Thank you so much! I get the point!
